# How can I suspend an app in Apple Store

Tags: iphone, app-store

Is there any way to suspend an app in the Apple Store.

My app is already published but I want to suspend it until I launch a new version?

The only options I found were changing the Avaiability Date or setting the Price Tier to something huge.

Is changing the avaiability date the best way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like you need to talk to Apple.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're looking for page 107 of the PDF version of the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/iTunesConnect_Guide.pdf).  The HTML version of [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/About.html) has a direct link to [Removing an App from Sale](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW17)

"After removing all assigned territory checkboxes from your app in the Rights and Pricing section, the status changes to Developer Removed from Sale and your app will not be seen on the App Store within 24 hours."

App restoration instructions are on the next page. :)

Answer (score 3):

In the page where you select the Availability Date and Price Tier you'll see a long list of countries. Deselect all the countries and save, your app will show as "Developer Removed from Sale" afterwards.